# Select em valor encriptado

Tags: mysql

Bom, eu criei uma tabela e inseri um valor em um campo usando o SHA1(encrypt), e não sei como selecionar o valor por esse campo encriptado.
TABELA:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `quest`;
USE `quest`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users`( 
`username` CHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`password` CHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`perm` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
);
```

INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO `users`(`username`, `password`, `email`, `perm`) VALUES ("admin", SHA1("admin"), "email@email.com", 2);
```

Tentei fazer assim:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `password` = SHA1('admin')
```

Retorna:

```
 MySQL não retornou nenhum registo. (O Query demorou 0.0040 sec)
```

Alguem sabe como faz? Obrigado.

Comment: `password` precisa ter 40 caracteres, não 32.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `password` LIKE SHA1('admin')
```

**Editado:**

Achei o seu problema, o SHA1 retorna uma cadeia de 40 caracteres. Como o seu banco possui apenas 32. O seu SHA1(password) foi truncado. Possuindo somente os 32 primeiros caracteres da sua sequência. Recomendo que você altere o tamanho da coluna password para 40.

Comment: MySQL não retornou nenhum registo. (O Query demorou 0.0020 sec)
:C

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou.